# Showing progress dialog while getting data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and i want to show progress dialog while fetching data from firebase. I have achieved this but the problem is i cannot dismiss the dialog when some network error occurs while fetching. I know OnDataChange method is called when data is loaded without errors from firebase but what if some error occurs. Which method is called then?

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stories, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    showProgressDialog("Please Wait...");
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("content");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG,"On Data Change");
            if(mProgressDialog != null){
                mProgressDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG,"On Cancelled");

            if(mProgressDialog != null){
                mProgressDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not that some network error occurs, onCancelled() of valueEventListener does not even get called.
I tried to use object of class which extends AsyncTask<> to show progress dialog in its doInBackground() but it only helped me retrieve data only once even though i have changed the database reference. If i do not use object of this class, I have no idea how to show progress dialog until my data is retrieved from database, but it is working fine. The problem which stands in my way is how to show progress dialog for retrieving data from firebase database without using AsyncTask<>.

Answer (score 3):

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

mProgressDialog.setMessage("Work ...");
mProgressDialog.show();

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                    .child("child node")
                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                                               do something
                                               mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                            } else {

                                               mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                               Snackbar.make(v, "datasnapshot is null", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();

                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                           mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
```

Comment: onCancelled is not called on Network Error...tried it but doesnt work

Comment: I have edited the question with my code. Please take a look. Thank you